# green smoke turns blue

Tags: smoke-simulation

After adding a gas domain and a **planar**, green (0, 1, 0) smoke inflow with an initial velocity, the resulting smoke is not green (1, 0, 0).

[image]

[image: green smoke turns blue]

This happens with every color except for (1, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 1). How can I make the smoke color stay consistent?

Comment: i would say: it is a bug. If you use a "normal" volume shader and change to render display - it works.

Comment: @Chris It may be a bug, but the behaviour is independent of [Rendering Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlEjm.png). The wrong colors seem to be baked into the geometry information.

Comment: If I give a volume shader in render mode, I got the color of that volume shader.

Comment: I am using the smoke color attribute for multicolored smoke.